# what is the function to find otsu threshold in emgu cv?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I don't need the thresholded image. I want the threshold. I found this in OpenCV.

```
cv::threshold( orig_img, thres_img, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY+CV_THRESH_OTSU );
```

Is there an equivalent in EmguCv. Thanks in advance.

PS. I need to use this threshold for canny edge detector

Comment: no idea about emgu, but the *return value* of cv::threshold is the otsu threshold in the above case. (so you probably still need to call cv::threshold, even if you throw away the thresh_img)

Comment: Thanks! I called the threshold function through CvInvoke and it works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can refer this code for Auto Canny Edge detector!

```
Image<Gray, byte> Img_Source_Gray = Img_Org_Gray.Copy();
Image<Gray, byte> Img_Egde_Gray = Img_Source_Gray.CopyBlank();
Image<Gray, byte> Img_SourceSmoothed_Gray = Img_Source_Gray.CopyBlank();
Image<Gray, byte> Img_Otsu_Gray = Img_Org_Gray.CopyBlank();

Img_SourceSmoothed_Gray = Img_Source_Gray.SmoothGaussian(3);
double CannyAccThresh = CvInvoke.cvThreshold(Img_EgdeNR_Gray.Ptr, Img_Otsu_Gray.Ptr, 0, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_OTSU | Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY);
double CannyThresh = 0.1 * CannyAccThresh;
Img_Otsu_Gray.Dispose();

Img_Egde_Gray = Img_SourceSmoothed_Gray.Canny(CannyThresh, CannyAccThresh);
imageBox2.Image = Img_Egde_Gray;
```

Comment: Thanks. It works!. I did not know that you can call OpenCV functions directly using CvInvoke.

Comment: I know this post is quite old but does anybody know the equivalence code for EmguCV 3.x? Because it does not contains the function CvInvoke.cvThreshold and the enum Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.

Comment: This thread is old, but in answer to the previous commenter's question, I found the new enums at Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Otsu &  Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary