# Remove separated objects in an Image C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

your help is much appreciated. I am using C# and EmguCV for image processing

I have tried noise removal, but nothing happens. I also tried image median filter, and it only works on the first image, but it does not work on the second image. It only makes the second image blurry and the objects larger and more square-like.

I want to **remove obviously distinct objects**(green ones)  in my image below so that it would turn all black because they are obviously separated and are not grouped unlike the second image below.

Image 1:

[image: It said that i need 10 reputation to post images, so this is image 1 :(]

At the same way, I want to do it in my image below, but **remove only those objects -- (the black ones) -- that are not grouped/(lumped?)** so that what remains on the image are the objects that are grouped/larger in scale?

Image 2:

[image: It said that i need 10 reputation to post images, so this is image 2 :(]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may try Gaussian Blur and then apply Threshold to the image.

Gaussian Blur is a widely used effect in graphics software, typically to **reduce image noise** and **reduce detail**, which I think matches your requirements well.

---

#### For your 1st image:

`CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(srcImg, destImg, new Size(0, 0), 5);//You may need to customize Size and Sigma depends on different input image.`

You will get:

[image]

Then

`CvInvoke.Threshold(srcImg, destImg, 10, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary);`

You will get:

[image]

---

#### For your 2nd image:

`CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(srcImg, destImg, new Size(0, 0), 5);//You may need to customize Size and Sigma depends on different input image.`

You will get:

[image]

Then

`CvInvoke.Threshold(srcImg, destImg, 240, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary);`

You will get:

[image]

Hope this help!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, our internet connection was down for almost 2 days. 

On the first image, I dont want to blur it out, but the result is what i wanted.

On the second image, I also dont want to blur it out because my desired output is not full green. I just want to turn the distinct little 'spots' on the image so that what remains in the image are the large spots

Answer (score 0):

You should first threshold the image using Otsus method. Second run connected component analysis on the threshold image. Third go over all the component that you found and for the ones that have a size that is smaller than some min size delete it from the original image.

1. cvThreshold (with CV_THRESH_BINARY/CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV(choose according to the image) + CV_THRESH_OTSU) http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/9624cb8e-921e-12a0-3c21-7821f0deb402.htm + http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/bc08707a-63f5-9c73-18f4-aeab7878d7a6.htm
2. CvInvoke.FindContours (RetrType == External,ChainApproxNone)
3. For each contour that we found in 2 calculate CvInvoke.ContourArea
4. If area is smaller than minArea draw on the original image(The one you want to filter) the value you want for them(0 I suppose) in the original image using CvInvoke.DrawContours with the current contour and with thickness==-1 to fill the inside of the contour.

Comment: I have already used binary thresholding using this code

    Image<Gray, Byte> img_colour = new Image<Gray, Byte>(new Bitmap(pBox.Image));
            img_colour = img_colour.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(100), new Gray(255));

but i cant seem to work the cv thresh otsu for Emgu 3.0 and I tried to use this code i found [here][1]

thanks a lot for your help, and i appreciate it very much

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989754/what-is-the-function-to-find-otsu-threshold-in-emgu-cv

Comment: So exclude step 1

Comment: I accidentally clicked add comment, please check for edit, sir. thank you

Comment: You need this line of code CvInvoke.cvThreshold(Img_EgdeNR_Gray.Ptr, Img_Otsu_Gray.Ptr, 0, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_OTSU | Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY);

Comment: I already did that like this, but there is an error.
https://postimg.org/image/mydhrogzd/

Comment: Update: I have already fixed it and used Binary Thresholding then Otsu Thresholding, but I am confused. The results were the same when I only used Binary thresholding, so why still use otsu thresholding after binary thresholding?

I dont know how to do step 2 - 4 :( Your guidance to me is very much appreciated, sir. thank you

https://postimg.org/image/3s917dwg7/9b178f16/

Comment: First i think you can't do it one after the other. You need to use the command with both. But if the threshold image looks fine you can just use the binary thresholding.

Comment: For step 2 please refer to http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/cb24a129-d9ce-57f3-19ad-0eaa27a77317.htm. The input image is the output of the threshold.

Comment: Hello, we lost our internet connection before I was able to reply to you. Last Thursday, I have found other links in stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970577/finding-contour-points-in-emgucv)  about contours and have found one example in codeproject, but i really have a hard time understanding it. Tbh, I am a newbie in image processing. I am stuck with this(http://postimg.org/image/8gibmjczz/) as of this night, please elaborate further :( Thank you so much!

Comment: UPDATE: I have tried doing what you instructed me, but I am not sure if what I did is correct since I hurried up my research. This is what it looks like from the first process up to the third (http://postimg.org/image/508sjsosb/)

and this is what I did on the code based from combined examples from emgu forum and stackoverflow. (http://postimg.org/image/ks4evr9s5/). I dont understand the drawing part and I dont want to continue yeet if Im wrong at step 3. Please elaborate further on step 3 - 4 pls :( Hoping for your sincere reply of guidance later today, sir. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: step 3 calculate the size of each component using counter area. Step 4 If the area is smaller than some predefined threshold you can draw it in a new image. If there is more specific question you can ask and i will try to help

Comment: Hello, sir. Did I do what is right on the second step? Also, I don't understand what you mean by "counter area", sir. If you have much time, can you please explain it to me much further or show it into code snippets with comments? Thank you